# pass user id in slug and get user information

Tags: urls, slug, id, youtube

I have `user id` and I am getting all information using `user id` on page with slug.

When I pass the `user id` in slug then I am not getting user information on page.

For example I have `www.mysite.com/test` slug.

Can I pass user id like YouTube id `www.mysite.com/id=WZeVy5DKtNQ` in slug and get user information.

I am trying like this `www.mysite.com/test?id=123`

code:

```
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
$camp_link = get_site_url()."/campaign-detail/?id=".$user_id;
echo "<p class='campaign_store_name'><a href='".$camp_link."'>".$camp_title."</a></p>";
$arform_id = Get_ARFORM_ID_using_slug($camp_link );
```

Answer (score 1):

The code seems incomplete. Maybe the problem is simply that you define `$id` but then try to use `$user_id`? Also, I think `id` is a protected variable, so maybe use `my_id` instead.

Try this:

www.mysite.com/test?my_id=123

```
$user_id = $_REQUEST['my_id'];
$camp_link = get_site_url()."/campaign-detail/?id=".$user_id;
echo "<p class='campaign_store_name'><a href='".$camp_link."'>".$camp_title."</a></p>";
$arform_id = Get_ARFORM_ID_using_slug($camp_link);
```

Comment: i did this.i have pass user id in slug but i not getting user info on page

Comment: What do you mean by "not getting user info on page"? What kind of user info do you expect to get?

Comment: I modified my answer a bit, please give it a try. Make sure you got `$user_id` in both places, and that you use `my_id` behind the slug and in the first line.